# Hibernate throws converting data type exception

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I'm converting all our sql queries to use Hibernate parameters. Now when I add a parameter in my query and map it with an variable it always give me the error:

> ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Error converting data type
>   nvarchar to bigint.

It doesn't make any sense because I added a string parameter.

The query looks like:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT Sum([qtyrequired]) as pcs, o.materialrequireddate, itemid  "
                + "FROM   [materialManagement].[pcsorderrequirement] r  JOIN materialmanagement.pcsorders o  "
                + "ON o.id = r.pcsorderid  WHERE  itemid IN ( :items )   "
                + "AND Cast(o.materialrequireddate AS DATE) >= Cast(Getdate() AS DATE)  "
                + "AND o.materialrequireddate <= Cast( :endDate AS DATE)  "
                + "GROUP  BY o.materialrequireddate, itemid")
                .setString("items", items).setString("endDate", endDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
```

When I return to my original working query it looks like:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT Sum([qtyrequired]) as pcs, o.materialrequireddate, itemid  "
                + "FROM   [materialManagement].[pcsorderrequirement] r  " + "JOIN materialmanagement.pcsorders o  "
                + "ON o.id = r.pcsorderid  " + "WHERE  itemid IN (" + items + ")   "
                + "AND Cast(o.materialrequireddate AS DATE) >= Cast(Getdate() AS DATE)  "
                + "AND o.materialrequireddate <= Cast('" + endDate + "' AS DATE)  "
                + "GROUP  BY o.materialrequireddate, itemid");
```

What can create this exception when I use named parameters? I'm using Hibernate 5.1 and for the database MS SQL server.

Comment: The reason for the exception is you are passing a single string parameter for the list of itemId values. SQL Server expects separate integer parameter for each value in the `IN` clause. I can't speak to how to do that with Hibernate.

Comment: This is one example but I get it on every mapping also when I include a normal string value that will be placed not in an IN.

Comment: For scalar parameter values, specify the proper data type setter, like `setDate`. Also note that applying a function to a column in a query predicate will prevent indexes from being used efficiently. Consider refactoring `Cast(o.materialrequireddate AS DATE) >= Cast(Getdate() AS DATE)` as `o.materialrequireddate AS DATE >= Cast(Getdate() AS DATE)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my query to not cast to a date and sets the parameters with a correct type:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT Sum([qtyrequired]) as pcs, o.materialrequireddate, itemid  "
                + "FROM   [materialManagement].[pcsorderrequirement] r  JOIN materialmanagement.pcsorders o "
                + "ON o.id = r.pcsorderid  WHERE  itemid IN ( :items ) "
                + "AND Cast(o.materialrequireddate AS DATE) >= Cast(Getdate() AS DATE)  "
                + "AND o.materialrequireddate <= :endDate "
                + "GROUP  BY o.materialrequireddate, itemid").setParameterList("items", items.stream().map(Item::getId).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .setDate("endDate", Date.from(endDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
```